# Рандомные точки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подсажите как можно задавать 2 рандомные точки для системы координат. Через  randon пробовал но там только числа в виде  0.2543556655.

Comment: ну вызовите его 2 раза...

Comment: Какого типа и из какого диапазона нужны числа?

Comment: @mkkkik как на системе координат(0,6,12, -4  и тд)

Comment: Диапазон не важен, никакой графики там не будет, так что не важно, можно ограничить жо 100, не принцепиально

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, если речь о широте и долготе:

```
In [231]: lat = 90*(1 - 2*random.random())

In [232]: lon = 180*(1 - 2*random.random())

In [233]: lat
Out[233]: 42.64740900723997

In [234]: lon
Out[234]: -133.42966883061914
```

Если нужны целые в диапазоне: [-100, 100]:

```
In [240]: random.randint(-100, 100)
Out[240]: -33

In [241]: random.randint(-100, 100)
Out[241]: 94
```

Answer (score 1):

Для получения пары случайных положительных целых чисел:

```
from random import choices
r = range(100) # верхняя граница диапазона
x, y = choices(r, k=2)
print(x, y)
```